# PowerShell. Скрип который смотрел на последний за 24 часа файл и записывал только размер его

Tags: windows, powershell, резервное-копирование

подскажите не могу правильно написать скрипт, как заставить PowerShell что бы среди файлов искал последний созданный и записал размер файла в txt?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Конечно! Вот пример скрипта на PowerShell, который ищет последний созданный файл в указанной директории и записывает его размер в файл txt:

```
# Укажите путь к директории, в которой нужно искать файл
$dirPath = "C:\Users\Username\Documents"

# Получаем список файлов в директории, сортируем по дате создания
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $dirPath | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending

# Получаем первый файл из отсортированного списка (последний созданный)
$latestFile = $files[0]

# Получаем размер файла в байтах
$fileSize = $latestFile.Length

# Укажите путь к файлу, в который нужно записать размер последнего созданного файла
$outputFilePath = "C:\Users\Username\Documents\fileSize.txt"

# Записываем размер файла в txt файл
Set-Content -Path $outputFilePath -Value $fileSize
```

Вы можете изменить путь к директории и путь к файлу вывода, чтобы они соответствовали вашей среде. Если вам нужно искать файлы по другому критерию, чем дата создания, вы можете изменить параметры Sort-Object функции Get-ChildItem.

Comment: А можно сделать интервал, к примеру нету за 24 файла он пишет 0?

Comment: Get-ChildItem -Path D:\folder | where LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(24) не показывает, хотя там файлы есть

Comment: А нашел ошибку благодарю

Answer (score -2):

```
# Укажите путь к директории, в которой нужно искать файл
$dirPath = "D:\Folder"

# Получаем файл созданный за последние 24 часа
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $dirPath | where LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)

# Получаем первый файл из отсортированного списка (последний созданный)
$latestFile = $files

# Получаем размер файла в байтах
$fileSize = $latestFile.Length

# Укажите путь к файлу, в который нужно записать размер последнего созданного файла
$outputFilePath = "D:\Folder\fileSize.txt"

# Записываем размер файла в txt файл
Set-Content -Path $outputFilePath -Value $fileSize
```